# Firebase Firestore дождаться результата из addOnCompleteListener

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase, firestore

Делаю для практики простую игру на Андроид.
Результаты игроков (набранные очки) сохраняю в Firebase Firestore.
Решил сделать отображение рейтинга игрока.
Логика такая:

- Какой-то игрок на одну позицию выше чем текущий игрок
- Текущий игрок
- Какой-то игрок на одну позицию ниже чем текущий игрок

Метод возвращающий PlayerEnvironment (дата класс) содержащий данные на указанных игроков и позицию игрока  рейтинге:

```
private fun getPlayerEnvironment(
        playerPoints: Int,
        playerStatisticData: StatisticData
    ): PlayerEnvironment = runBlocking {
        val onTopPlayer = getOnTop(playerPoints)
        Log.d(TAG,"onTopPlayer: $onTopPlayer")
        val onBellowPlayer = getFromBellow(playerPoints)
        Log.d(TAG,"onBellowPlayer: $onBellowPlayer")
        val playerPosition = getPlayerPosition(playerPoints)
        Log.d(TAG,"playerPosition $playerPosition")

        return@runBlocking PlayerEnvironment(
            playerPosition = playerPosition,
            playerStatisticData = playerStatisticData,
            onTopPlayerStatisticData = onTopPlayer,
            onBellowPlayerStatisticData = onBellowPlayer
        )
    }
```

Получение статистики игрока выше рангом:

```
private suspend fun getOnTop(playerPoints: Int): StatisticData {
        val snap = db.collection(FB_COLLECTION_NAME)
            .whereGreaterThan("totalPoints", playerPoints)
            .orderBy("totalPoints")
            .limit(1)
            .get()
            .await()
        return snap.documents[0].toObject<StatisticData>()!!
    }
```

Получение статистики игрока ниже рангом:

```
private suspend fun getFromBellow(playerPoints: Int): StatisticData {
        val snap = db.collection(FB_COLLECTION_NAME)
            .whereLessThan("totalPoints", playerPoints)
            .orderBy("totalPoints", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .limit(1)
            .get()
            .await()
        return snap.documents[0].toObject<StatisticData>()!!
    }
```

Получение позиции игрока:

```
private suspend fun getPlayerPosition(playerPoints: Int): Int {
        val query = db.collection(FB_COLLECTION_NAME)
            .whereGreaterThan("totalPoints", playerPoints)
            .orderBy("totalPoints")
        val countQuery = query.count()
        var result = -1
        countQuery.get(AggregateSource.SERVER)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val snapshot = task.result
                    result = snapshot.count.toInt()
                    Log.d(TAG, "Count: ${snapshot.count}")
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Count failed: ${task.toString()}")
                }
                return@addOnCompleteListener
            }
        return result
    }
```

Реализация метода [как в документации](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries?hl=ru#kotlin%20ktx_1).

И вот тут собственно вопрос.
При таком решении метод **getPlayerPosition()** всегда возвращает -1, не дожидаясь выполнения из слушателя.
Как заставить его ждать? Или вообще вернуть из метода значение **result = snapshot.count.toInt()**
Пробовал после добавления слушателя добавлять **.await()**, но тогда на этом месте выполнение зависает вообще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсказал решение хороший человек :) Возможно кому-нибудь пригодится:

```
private suspend fun getPlayerEnvironment(
        playerPoints: Int,
        playerStatisticData: StatisticData
    ): PlayerEnvironment = runBlocking {
        val onTopPlayer = getOnTop(playerPoints)
        val onBellowPlayer = getFromBellow(playerPoints)
        val playerPosition = getPlayerPosition(playerPoints)
        return@runBlocking PlayerEnvironment(playerPosition, playerStatisticData, onTopPlayer, onBellowPlayer)
    }

private suspend fun getPlayerPosition(playerPoints: Int): Int = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
        val query = db.collection(FB_COLLECTION_NAME)
            .whereGreaterThan("totalPoints", playerPoints)
            .orderBy("totalPoints")
        val countQuery = query.count()

        countQuery.get(AggregateSource.SERVER)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val snapshot = task.result
                    val result = snapshot.count.toInt()
                    Log.d(TAG, "Count: ${snapshot.count}")
                    continuation.resume(result)
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Count failed: ${task.toString()}")
                    continuation.resumeWithException(Exception("Failed to get player position"))
                }
            }
    }
```

**getPlayerEnvironment** так же вызывается в корутине.